# Image Not Showing Up on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

So I have a UIScrollView and scrolling works. I added a label on it and it scrolled that too. When I added an Image View, however, scrolling works but the image does not show up and I get this error:

```
Could not load the "block" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier
```

My ViewController.m:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView * scroller;
}

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];  
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

I have disabled "Use Auto Layout," Changed the Size to "Freeform," and changed the views height to 600.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: Is the image you are trying to load named block? Do you see a preview for that image in Interface Builder? What file type is the image?

Comment: Yeah it shows up in XCode but not in the iOS Stimulator. Its a PNG, named 'block.png,' and it's in the Supporting Files directory. I removed all my added code and the Scroll View and it showed it fine, but doesn't work with those added.

Comment: Where is the file being referenced, and are you sure its not a photoshop image saved as block.png? It happens frequently.

Comment: You were actually right... That's a bit embarrassing...